# R sankeyNetwork d3.scaleOrdinal() - why the colors of the last two nodes do not change

Tags: r, colors, sankey-diagram

I am working on manually changing the color of the bars in a sankey diagram, but for the last three categories, the colors do not vary according to the new color_scale and "yellow" is assigned to all of the three last categories.

'''

```
color_scale <- 'd3.scaleOrdinal().
                  range(["gainsboro","dimgray", "black" , 
"darkred","red","tomato", "lightsalmon", 
"royalblue","blue",  "midnightblue", "deepskyblue", 
"yellow", "green","red"])'
sankeyNetwork(Links = resparking$links, Nodes = resparking$nodes, Source = "source",
              Target = "target", Value = "value", NodeID = "name",
              units = "Number of Houses", 
              fontSize = 20, nodeWidth = 30, 
              colourScale = JS(color_scale))
```

'''

The data can be downloaded here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1hPq-PvW89hsVylrLA0anqDFB-OrjBJIz/view?usp=sharing

The graph and data look like this:
[enter image description here][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2EqAF.png

Comment: It's easier to help you if you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Share data in a `dput()` format rather than an image.

Comment: Thank you! I added a download link for the dataset.